# How to use x-www-form-urlencoded in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exact-online

Am trying to access the token from [ExactOnlineAPI](https://developers.exactonline.com/#OAuth_Tutorial.html%3FTocPath%3DAuthentication%7C_____2) but the documentation recommends to only use  `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Does Ruby on Rails has this kind of encoding, if so how can i use it.

What is the different between `x-www-form-urlencoded` and `encode_www_form`

```
 params =  {
             :code => "#{code}",
             :redirect_uri => '/auth/exact/callback',
             :grant_type   => "authorization_code",
             :client_id   => "{CLIENT_ID}",
             :client_secret => "CLIENT_SECRET"
           }
uri = URI('https://start.exactonline.nl/api/oauth2/token')
#
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
puts "Access Token: "+res.body
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Request bodies are defined by a form’s markup. In the form tag there
>   is an attribute called `enctype`, this attribute tells the browser how
>   to encode the form data. There are several different values this
>   attribute can have. The default is application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
>   which tells the browser to encode all of the values.

so when we want to send data to submit the form by those data as a params of the form the header will send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for define enctype

```
http.set_form_data(param_hash)
```

For your

```
params =  {
         :code => "#{code}",
         :redirect_uri => '/auth/exact/callback',
         :grant_type   => "authorization_code",
         :client_id   => "{CLIENT_ID}",
         :client_secret => "CLIENT_SECRET"
       }
  uri = URI('https://start.exactonline.nl/api/oauth2/token')
  #

  Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri).set_form_data(params)
```

or for post request of form submission use `Net::HTTP::Post`

and `encode_www_form` is:

It Generate URL-encoded form data from given enum.

```
URI.encode_www_form([["name", "ruby"], ["language", "en"]])
#=> "name=ruby&language=en"
```

in your case

```
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
#=> "code=aas22&redirect_uri=...."
```

More info [Here](http://apidock.com/ruby/URI/encode_www_form/class)

Comment: Hey **Raj**, Am having a problem to  implement the example you gave me. Could you please write for me a clear  example depending on the example I posted.

Comment: yes for your api you need to use http.set_form_data({params})

Comment: Hey **Raj**, I meant an example like for  **KingChintz**. Could you please post it.

Answer (score 6):

To put it in simple terms, if you need to POST a application/www-url-form-encoded request:

```
# prepare the data:
params = [ [ "param1", "value1" ], [ "param2", "value2" ], [ "param3", "value3" ] ]

uri = ( "your_url_goes_here" )

# make your request:
response = Net::HTTP.post_form( uri, params )
if( response.is_a?( Net::HTTPSuccess ) )
    # your request was successful
    puts "The Response -> #{response.body}"
else
    # your request failed
    puts "Didn't succeed :("
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with a `Net::HTTP` object and therefore can't use the `post_form` class method, encode the form values yourself, and provide the encoded value as the data string.

```rb
def post_form(path, form_params)
  encoded_form = URI.encode_www_form(form_params)
  headers = { content_type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
  http_client.request_post(path, encoded_form, headers)
end

def http_client
  http_client = Net::HTTP.new(@host, @port)
  http_client.read_timeout = @read_timeout
  http_client.use_ssl = true
  http_client
end
```

This is [what `Net::HTTP.post_form` does internally](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/139634a16fc5fa6779b08aeb89f40b289579c4bf/lib/net/http/header.rb#L416-L423).